# How do I specify a geographic location with the HTML "time" element?

Tags: html

The HTML5 specs [for the `time` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/textlevel-semantics.html#the-time-element) have a note under the heading "A valid time-zone offset string" that says this:

> For times without dates (or times referring to events that recur on multiple dates), specifying the geographic location that controls the time is usually more useful than specifying a time zone offset, because geographic locations change time zone offsets with daylight savings time. [...]

While I totally agree with this statement, I have been wondering - and this is my question - **how can I specify a geographic location in the `time` element?** I've been looking through the specs but I haven't found a clue. Additional web research also didn't yield any useful information. Can someone point me in the right direction?

BTW: I'm a beginner in web programming, and although this really seems to be just a minor detail I like to get things right from the start.

Comment: Do you mean timezones, or longitude and longitude?

Comment: @Jerfov2 As I wrote, the specs say "specifying the **geographic location** [...] is usually more useful than specifying a **time zone offset**". In my opinion latitude/longitude clearly qualify as "geographic location", but maybe there are other ways how to specify a geographic location?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: @Jerfov2 No. The geolocation API is used to get the user's geographic location. What I'm looking for is how I can **specify** the location in the HTML markup. The HTML5 specs seem to imply that this can be done, but they don't say how (or I am misunderstanding something).

Comment: `<time …>…</time> in Paris`

Comment: @Ryan I would have thought that since the `time` element is all about providing a date/time in machine-readable format, that the word "specify" in "**specifying** the geographic location" is meant in a technical sense. So you say that this is just a hint to content creators?

Comment: @herzbube Yes, I’m pretty sure that’s the case.

Comment: I read the spec the same way @Ryan does. There’s no technical way to add a geolocation to the time element, but specifying a human readable explanation can be more accurate than a timezone offset, as the offset changes with daylight savings. Note this applies when the date is not known, or for multiple recurring dates, as there’s no way knowing if the timestamp in question is refering to a date during daylight savings or not.

Comment: Good question though!

Comment: @agrm. - I think the idea would be to be able to specify "19:30 [Europe/Paris]" using one of the standard [Timezone Identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/#tzids). With a recurring event, these times would get combined with specific dates, and then the location could be used to resolve whether or not daylight savings time was in operation for the combined date and time by referring to the [Timezone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). However, the datetime value of a time element does not appear to allow for that.

Comment: @Alohci Yes, that would also seem to be a geographical location that satisfies the note in the specs - even for the Samoa example (Samoa apparently changed timezones at the end of 2011). A machine interpreting the time for a specific date "simply" would look up the time zone in which Samoa (or "Europe/Paris") is located at that date, and could then apply the correct timezone offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to specify `<time>` via **region** with raw HTML. I believe the documentation is simply stating that it's more **useful** to do it based on region, not that it is necessarily **possible** with raw HTML. This can certainly be achieved with a **back-end** language however, and injected into the `<time>` element (or `datetime` attribute).

Timezones can be specified with `+`, offset in relation to GMT:

```html
<!-- GMT+1 (like Italy) -->
<time>+01:00</time>
```

And can be combined with fully-qualified times as well:

```html
<!-- 16th September 2014 at 18 hours, 20 minutes, and 30 seconds
     in a time zone of GMT+1 (like Italy) -->
<time>2014-09-16T18:20:30+01:00</time> in Italy
```

As is demonstrated above, perhaps the best you can do is explicitly state the relevant region, such as `<time …>…</time>` in Italy.

In order to retrieve the geographic timezone, IANA has **[a list](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)** of all applicable timezones per region.

Dates should be in the format `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM[:SS[.mmm]]` or `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM[:SS[.mmm]]`, where:

- `H` stands for hours
- `M` stands for minutes
- `S` stands for seconds
- `m` stands for milliseconds
- The square brackets indicate the parts that are optional

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

From  [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp):

> Definition and Usage
>
> The  tag defines a human-readable date/time.
>
> This element can also be used to encode dates and times in a machine-readable way so that user agents can offer to add birthday reminders or scheduled events to the user's calendar, and search engines can produce smarter search results.

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time):

> The HTML time element represents either a time on a 24-hour clock or a precise date in the Gregorian calendar (with optional time and timezone information).

So in other words, the `time` element isn't really supposed to be used for a precise geolocation, but maybe a timezone. For location, like @Ryan suggested, do something along the lines of `<time …>…</time> in Paris`

Comment: After studying the HTML5 specs (link see OP) it seems clear to me that the whole point of the `time` element is to provide a machine-readable form of the date/time. The W3Schools statement that you quote ("The tag defines a human-readable date/time. This element can **also** be used to encode dates and times in a machine-readable way [...]" [emphasis mine]) is therefore, in my opinion, too casual and rather misleading. Nitpicking aside - it really seems to be impossible to add geolocation. Ah well...